# How can I create a button that works to show a link but has a onfocusout event working on it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Consider the set of codes I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body style="color: black;">
        <button id="button" onclick="start()" onfocusout="start()">Look Down</button>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a style="display: none;"; id="list" href="https://google.com/">Player-1</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

where my script file is:

```
function start(){
    var a=document.getElementById("list").style;
    if(a.display=="none") a.display="block";
    else a.display="none";
}
```

```js
function start() {
  var a = document.getElementById("list").style;
  if (a.display == "none") a.display = "block";
  else a.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="color: black;">
  <button id="button" onclick="start()" onfocusout="start()">Look Down</button>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a style="display: none;" ; id="list" href="https://google.com/">Player-1</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Here, the button Look Down when pressed shows the link Player-1. But when I click the option Player-1, I lose the option as I have come out of focus of the button. As a result, I can't go to the link I intend to go to. So, how can I fix this? I mean I want to click the link after pressing the button but don't want to come out of the focus.

Comment: @Yogi Any other suggestions? I have done it.

Answer (score 2):

### Behavior

- When the user clicks the `<button>`, `start()` is called and the `<a>` is revealed, good .
- When the user clicks the `<a>`, the `<button>` loses it's focus to `<a>` which triggers a "focusout" event on `<button>` thereby calling `start()` again which removes the `<a>`, bad .

### Solutions

1. Simply remove the `onfocusout` inline event handler (see **Figure I** and **Example A**).
2. If you want `<a>` to disappear if anything *but* `<button>` and `<a>` is clicked, then you just want `<a>` to disappear and not toggle between *there* and *gone* which is what `start()` does. To get aforementioned behavior, delegate the "click" event by registering a common ancestor element and making the "click" event handler determine specific behavior for specific elements (see **Example B** and [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation)).

   **Figure I**

   ```
   <!-- WRONG -->
   <button id="button" onclick="start()" onfocusout="start()"> 
     Look Down 
   </button>

   <!-- CORRECT -->
   <button id="button" onclick="start()">
     Look Down 
   </button>
   ```

### Example A

**Layout Corrections**

- `<html>` will have only a single `<head>` and a single `<body>` as direct children.
- `<head>` proceeds `<body>`.
- `<meta>`, `<title>`, `<link>`, and `<style>` are in the `<head>` (preferably in that order).
- `<script>` can be in the `<head>` as well, but 99% of the time should reside within `<body>` at the very bottom (in other words: as the last children of the `<body>` right before the closing tag: `</body>`)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body style="color: black;">
  <button id="button" onclick="start()"> Look Down </button>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="https://example.com" id="list" style="display: none;">
          Player-1
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <script>
    function start() {
      const a = document.getElementById("list").style;
      a.display = a.display === "none" ? "block" : "none";
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

### Example B

**Event Handling**

- [Inline event handlers are garbage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these). `onclick` and `onfocusout` have been removed from `<button>`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="button"> Look Down </button>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="https://example.com" id="list" style="display: none;">
          Player-1
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <script>
    // Reference <a>
    const A = document.getElementById("list");

    // Reference <button>
    const B = document.getElementById("button");

    // Register the click event to the Document Object
    document.onclick = start;

    function start(event) {

      // Reference the element clicked by the user.
      const clicked = event.target;

      // Access <a> style property
      const a = A.style;

      // If the user clicked <button>...
      if (clicked === B) {

        // ...toggle <a> between "there" and "gone"...
        a.display = a.display === "none" ? "block" : "none";

        // ...or if the user clicked <a>...
      } else if (clicked === A) {

        // ...exit function...
        return;

        // ...otherwise...
      } else {

        // ...hide <a>
        a.display = "none";
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Solution without JavaScript (only CSS)

If you solve this with a JS function it will run whenever clicking on the rest of the page. There's no need of slowing your sites performance and using that processor power from the visitors.

Moreover, an -only CSS- approach will allow visitors that have JavaScript disabled to interact with the site and effectively see the link when clicking the button.

The following would be the code without JS. The link is displayed as a block (with red background) so it can have a transition effect and delay that allows people to click it before dissapearing:

```css
#button:focus + table tr td #list {
  height: 20px !important;
}

#list{
  background:red;
  overflow:hidden;
  display:block;
  height:0px;
  transition: height 1s;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body style="color: black;">
        <button id="button">Look Down</button>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Content Before
                    <a id="list" href="https://example.com/">Player-1</a>
                    Content After
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```